# I would like to append different values to a dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have my array with data referring to different subjects divided in 3 different groups

`A = ([12, 13, 15], [13, 16, 18], [15, 15, 17])`

I want to append these to 3 different arrays, but I don't want to do it "manually" since I should use this code for bigger set of data.
So, I was looking for a way to create as many arrays as the amount of subjects (in this case 3) assigning to them different "names".

Looking on this site I ended up using a dictionary and this is what I did

```
number_of_groups = len(A)
```

```
groups = {"group" + str(i+1) : [] for i in range(number_of_groups)}
```

and this is the output:

`{'group1': [], 'group2': [], 'group3': []}`

now I wasn't able to append to each of them the 3 different set of data. I expect to have:

`{'group1': [12, 13, 15], 'group2': [13, 16, 18], 'group3': [15, 15, 17]}`

I tried this (I know is not a good way to do it...)

```
for n in A:
    for key in paths: paths[key].append(n)
```

output:

```
{'group1': [array([12,  13, 15]),array([13, 16, 18]),array([15, 15, 17])],
```

```
'group2': [array([12,  13, 15]),array([13, 16, 18]),array([15, 15, 17])],
```

```
'group3': [array([12,  13, 15]),array([13, 16, 18]),array([15, 15, 17])]}
```

Answer (score 1):

[I'mahdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740577/) had already suggested [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays)-[comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) to build the correct `list` in first place. In addition, you can use `enumerate` to iterate all elements `a` with index `i` of the `tuple` `A`:

```py
groups = {
    f"group{i+1}": a
    for i, a in enumerate(A)
}
```

As [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637585/) pointed out, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) has an optional `start` parameter for the iteration index, so you can simplify this further to:

```py
groups = {
    f"group{i}": a
    for i, a in enumerate(A, 1)
}
```

Comment: `enumerate` allows a start value, allowing you to avoid the `i+1` and simply use `i` by using `enumerate(A, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a nested loop. The outer one iterates over each group, then the inner one appends each group. To edit your current code, you can try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like this:

```
for n, key in zip(A, paths):
    paths[key].append(n)
```

However, since you are already using a dictionary comprehension earlier, it is definitely easier to modify that and fill the dictionary at that step already instead of first creating it and then filling it. The following outputs what you need:

```
groups = {"group" + str(i+1) : group for i, group in enumerate(A)}

>>> {'group1': [12, 13, 15], 'group2': [13, 16, 18], 'group3': [15, 15, 17]}
```